# Math Computation with Checked Boxes

Tags: javascript, html

Having trouble trying to figure out how to add the value of a checked box to a total. In my case I'm trying to add the price of the checked boxes to the price of the original cost already. My function totals the cost of the original cost correctly I'm just not sure how to add the checked values to the function or to create a new one. Thanks in advance.

```
    <tr>
      <th> Small Pizza </th>
      <td> $9.00 </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  name = "smal" id = "small"  
                  size ="2" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Medium Pizza </th>
      <td> $11.00 </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  name = "medium" id = "medium"  
            size = "2" /> </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th> Large Pizza </th>
      <td> $13.00 </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  name = "large" id = "large"  
            size = "2"  /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <br><br>
    <!-- Each topping is only to be $1 extra -->
    <input type ="checkbox" name = "pepp" id ="pepp" > Pepperoni <br>
    <input type ="checkbox" name = "sausage" id ="sausage" > Sausage <br>
    <input type ="checkbox" name = "pineapple" id ="pineapple" > Pineapple <br>
    <input type ="checkbox" name = "bacon" id ="bacon" > Bacon<br>
    <input type ="checkbox" name = "mushroom" id ="mushroom" > Mushroom <br>

     <p>
    <input type = "button"  value = "Total Cost" 
           onclick ="computeCost();" />
    <input type = "text"  size = "5"  id = "txtCost" 
           name = "txtCost" onfocus ="this.blur();" />
  </p>
```

And my javascript function

```
    function computeCost()
     {
var small = document.getElementById("small").value;
small = Number(small);

var medium = document.getElementById("medium").value;
medium = Number(medium);

var large = document.getElementById("large").value;
large = Number(large);

document.getElementById("txtCost").value = small*9 + medium*11 + large*13;
}
```

Comment: Assign a `value` to the checkbox, of course.

Comment: RickHitchcock It's the Id for my textbox where the total where be presented. And @Blazemonger, that then adds all the values regardless of being checked or not.

Comment: Test the `checked` property before adding the value, then.

Comment: Having some difficulties understanding this. What is this actually supposed to do? Let's say, I chose 1 small, 2 large and check Pepperoni, pineapple and bacon. What should be the result?

Comment: @mmgross, as of right now it will give you the price of the 3 pizzas you chose. I should of included I want each topping to only be $1 extra. So to total the price including toppings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the checked status of Pepperoni as a boolean (true or false):

```
var pepp = document.getElementById("pepp").checked
```

In JavaScript, `true` is equivalent to the number 1, and `false` is equivalent to the number 0.  Assuming pepperoni costs an additional dollar, you could get its cost like this:

```
pepp * 1
```

… or more simply:

```
pepp
```

Since the toppings cost a dollar *per pizza*, you can calculate the cost of all the pizzas (like you've already done), then add the number of pizzas times the cost of the toppings:

```
var pepp  = document.getElementById("pepp").checked,
    saus  = document.getElementById("sausage").checked,
    pine  = document.getElementById("pineapple").checked,
    bacon = document.getElementById("bacon").checked,
    mush  = document.getElementById("mushroom").checked;

document.getElementById("txtCost").value = 
  (small*9 + medium*11 + large*13) +
  (small + medium + large) * (pepp + saus + pine + bacon + mush);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3qka8ag/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I made these changes:

*HTML*

- I gave every checkbox a value, so you could assign different prizes to different toppings
- I gave every topping the same name (you could also give them the same class and use `getElementByClassName` instead or simply query all checkboxes, but the latter means you can't have any checkboxes on your page other than the ones for your toppings.

*JS*

- I selected all elements with the name `topping` using `getElementByName` and put them into an array.
- Iterated through that array to see if any where checked
- added up the values of those that are checked.

Full solution with my changes here:

```js
function computeCost() {
  var toppings = document.getElementsByName("topping");
  var topping_prize = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < toppings.length; i++) {
    if (toppings[i].checked) {
      topping_prize += Number(toppings[i].value);
    }
  }

  var small = document.getElementById("small").value;
  small = Number(small);

  var medium = document.getElementById("medium").value;
  medium = Number(medium);

  var large = document.getElementById("large").value;
  large = Number(large);


  document.getElementById("txtCost").value = small * 9 + medium * 11 + large * 13 + topping_prize;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Small Pizza</th>
    <td>$9.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="smal" id="small" size="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Medium Pizza</th>
    <td>$11.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="medium" id="medium" size="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Large Pizza</th>
    <td>$13.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="large" id="large" size="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="pepp" value="1">Pepperoni
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="sausage" value="1">Sausage
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="pineapple" value="1">Pineapple
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="bacon" value="1">Bacon
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="mushroom" value="1">Mushroom
<br>

<p>
  <input type="button" value="Total Cost" onclick="computeCost();" />
  <input type="text" size="5" id="txtCost" name="txtCost" onfocus="this.blur();" />
</p>
```